# Can I set the href of <a> tag with the selected value of autocomplete input box

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to insert `city.value` in the `ng-href` link.
please help me, someone.

this is the textbox

```
<input id="city" name="states" type="text"
       class="txt-dep-ret input-icon-depart country-autocomplete ui-autocomplete-input form-control"
       placeholder="Select Origin" allow-custom="false"  autocomplete="off">
```

this is the button link with `ng-href`

```
<a id="sbutton" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
   style="background-color: #E28F13; font-size: 14px"
   ng-href="@Url.Action("Booking", "home")?Rooms={{rooms}}&Destination={{city}} &DepartureDate={{departuredate}}&ReturnDate={{returndate}}&Adults1={{Adults1}}&Children1={{Children1}}&C1Age1={{C1Age1}}&C1Age2={{C1Age2}}&C1Age3={{C1Age3}}&C1Age4={{C1Age4}}&Adults2={{Adults2}}&Children2={{Children2}}&C2Age1={{C2Age1}}&C2Age2={{C2Age2}}&C2Age3={{C2Age3}}&C2Age4={{C2Age4}}&Adults3={{Adults3}}&Children3={{Children3}}&C3Age1={{C3Age1}}&C3Age2={{C3Age2}}&C3Age3={{C3Age3}}&C3Age4={{C3Age4}}" 
   onclick="validate(event);"> Search </a>
```

I want to set the destination to `city.value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `ng-model` in your textbox input.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<input id="city" name="states" type="text" class="txt-dep-ret input-icon-depart country-autocomplete ui-autocomplete-input form-control"  placeholder="Select Origin" allow-custom="false"  autocomplete="off" ng-model="hash">
<a ng-href="https://www.google.lk/{{hash}}">Search</a>
</div>
```

Comment: didn't bind the values

Comment: sometimes it not binding :/

Comment: try to figure-out using brake-points which point that not work properly so then we can find solution.

Answer (score -1):

Should be able to just do `{{city.value}}`.
Edit: This is wrong, see my comment below or the other answer.

Also you need to escape the double quotes around Booking and home, or change them to single quotes.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? What does the url look like after angular parses it?

Comment: http://localhost:51406/Home/Booking%2c%20home?Rooms=1&Destination=%20&DepartureDate=12/29/2017&ReturnDate=12/30/2017&Adults1=1&Children1=0&C1Age1=0&C1Age2=0&C1Age3=0&C1Age4=0&Adults2=0&Children2=0&C2Age1=0&C2Age2=0&C2Age3=0&C2Age4=0&Adults3=0&Children3=0&C3Age1=0&C3Age2=0&C3Age3=0&C3Age4=0

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Home/Booking, home

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2110.0

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't read the original post carefully enough. You need to set an attribute on the input element `ng-model="city"`. Then you can just do `{{city}}`

Comment: http://localhost:51406/home/Booking?Rooms=1&Destination=%20&DepartureDate=12/29/2017&ReturnDate=12/30/2017&Adults1=1&Children1=0&C1Age1=0&C1Age2=0&C1Age3=0&C1Age4=0&Adults2=0&Children2=0&C2Age1=0&C2Age2=0&C2Age3=0&C2Age4=0&Adults3=0&Children3=0&C3Age1=0&C3Age2=0&C3Age3=0&C3Age4=0

Comment: Where are the other inputs (rooms, departuredate...) set? As other inputs or in the controller? What does your updated city input element look like?